Can not access app running in a VM inside OpenShift
I have created an OpenShift 4.14 Single Node Cluster. Inside that I deployed a VM using the web console. Inside that VM I deployed NGINX at port 80.
I can curl into the IP of the VM from inside the cluster. To access the cluster from outside, I followed this doc by RH to create a service, then route but it did not work. I also created a service, endpoint, then route. This also did not work.
Usually, we create a pod, then make a service, then use route to expose it. But this does not work for the VMs. Any idea how that's done?

So the solution is simple but different, I found this doc.
To create service using virtctl, not using oc, then it works.
